# Java JLabel HTML display garbled when font conflicts with system font

Tags: java, html, swing, encoding, jlabel

**UPDATED** - problem is now solved in an ugly way - but there must be a proper way to do it?

I am having problems rendering text in a custom font, in HTML in a JLabel *when the font name conflicts with the name of a font already installed on the system*.

The system font is in a different format (otf vs ttf) so unsurprisingly the text is garbled.

The call to `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont` returns false to show the font failed to register.  So I guess the question is, is there a way to use this font without registering, or a way to rename it before registering?

I have now solved my problem by editing the ttf file and mangling the font name to make a conflict extremely unlikely, but I'm guessing there must be a proper way to handle this situation.

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyComponent extends JPanel {
    Font font; String text;
    public MyComponent(Font f) {font=f;}
    public void initSwing()
    {
        final String labelcontents = "<html><center>foo</center></html>";
        System.out.println(labelcontents);
        JLabel text = new JLabel(labelcontents);
        text.setFont(font);
        add(text,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestApplet extends JApplet {
        public void init()
        {
            Font mainFont = null;
            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("fonts/Exo-Bold.ttf");
            try {
                mainFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is).deriveFont(24f);
                System.out.println(mainFont.getName());
                boolean registered=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(mainFont);
                System.out.println("registered "+registered);
            } catch (FontFormatException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            final Container fframe = (JComponent)(getContentPane());
            final MyComponent component = new MyComponent(mainFont);

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { try {

                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {public void run() {
                        fframe.add(component);
                        component.initSwing();
                        fframe.revalidate();
                        fframe.repaint();
                    }});

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } }
            });
            t.start();
        }
}
```

Comment: The Exo-Bold font that is used in the code above can - for example - be downloaded from http://www.1001freefonts.com/d/5755/exo.zip?

Comment: I don't recall its source now but it was from a free font collection

Comment: Perhaps you could share your font file? Do you see the same problems for a default font?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the text contained HTML commands with charset or such.

```
String text1 = "<html><body>"
    + text.replace("&", "&amp;")
          .replace("<", "&lt;")
          .replace(">", "&gt;");
    + "</body></html>";
```

Comment: Good thought but it doesn't.  The only html it contains is `<br/>`.  (I want it to support `<i>` but the case above doesn't have it).

Answer (score 1):

Very strange. When I run your example applet on my laptop, the output seems fine:

[image: Screenshot with perfectly nice spelled "foo"]

I have used this [zip file](http://www.1001freefonts.com/d/5755/exo.zip) with the "Exo-Bold.ttf" file and am using Java 8 (version 1.8.0_65 of the Oracle JDK) on Windows 8.1.

This is the adapted version of your code that I ran:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyComponent extends JPanel {
    Font font; String text;
    public MyComponent(Font f) {font=f;}
    public void initSwing()
    {
        final String labelcontents = "<html><center>foo</center></html>";
        System.out.println(labelcontents);
        JLabel text = new JLabel(labelcontents);
        text.setFont(font);
        add(text,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestApplet extends JApplet {
    public void init()
    {
        Font mainFont = null;

        try {
            //InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("fonts/Exo-Bold.ttf");
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/Freek/[...]/Exo-Bold.ttf");
            mainFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is)
                           .deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f);
            is.close();
            System.out.println(mainFont.getName());
            boolean result = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                                                .registerFont(mainFont);
            System.out.println("Result registerFont: " + result);
        } catch (FontFormatException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        final Container fframe = (JComponent)(getContentPane());
        final MyComponent component = new MyComponent(mainFont);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { try {

                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {public void run() {
                    fframe.add(component);
                    component.initSwing();
                    fframe.revalidate();
                    fframe.repaint();
                }});

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Java 1.8.66 on Windows 7 x64.  Would installing the same font (possibly as .otf) on the system cause the problem do you think?

Comment: It could be related to the font file. To be clear: I didn't install the font, but downloaded it so the applet could use it.

Comment: Ok see update 2.  I have managed to troubleshoot some more by replicating the problem on a second machine.  If I install Exo Bold as opentype font the second machine gets a garbled display also.  This remains the case even after uninstalling Exo Bold again.

Comment: Updated again.  I have solved the problem by renaming the font in the ttf resource to a long and mangled name unlikely to conflict with anything.  Thanks for your help, and for my own purposes I'm happy.  For the sake of future visitors, I'm aware this solution is a kludge so would be interested to know if there is a better way to do it.  So consider yourself entitled to some of the bounty, and if you or anyone else can provide a better solution they can have the rest of it!

Comment: Great news and a kludge is a better solution than no solution! One small issue (that is not causing the problem): according to the [JavaDocs of the `Font.createFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,%20java.io.InputStream)) method (for Java 7): "This method does not close the InputStream." So I think it would be nice to add `is.close();` after creating the font.